# Do the infinitesimals have to be equal

Tags: calculus

When we are dealing with riemann sums, we partition an interval into some equally spaced sub intervals $\Delta x$ and $dx$ is basically when $\Delta x$ goes to $0$. Now when we are asked to find the area of a curve,we take a thin strip of length $dx$ and some vertical height $f(x)$ and we denote the resulting area by $dA$ and then use $\int dA$ to get the total area $A$. But the $dA$'s are are not all equal. I mean although width $dx$ is same,the vertical height varies,e.g it can ve very long and can be very short, then how do we say that all of these infinitesimals are $dA$?

Comment: [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), in general, don't require equally spaced sub intervals.

Comment: We are not saying they are equal. The differential $dA$ is a variable, and changes with $x,$ since it has the form $f(x)dx,$ and in general $f(x)$ can be any continuous function, not just a constant.

Comment: Intuitively, $dA$ is a differential piece of area located in the interval $[x,x+dx]$, it can be different from one point to another even if you assume $dx$ is fixed. Adding up all these differential areas yields the entire area anyway. But when working formally, we usually don't use differentials as real objects at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a very curious side opinion. It has nothing to do with reality.

Comment: @Ian How can you use *usually* and *at all* to refer to the same object within the same sentence? Is this an attempt to share a personal opinion, masked as fact? Differentials are sometimes used, and their use -- contrary to the furore in the 19th century -- has been shown to be consistent and without any logical flaws.

Comment: @Allawonder To be more explicit: in the usual practice of analysis, differentials are not used as real objects at all. In the use of the word "usually" I was attempting to avoid exactly this conversation about the existence of nonstandard analysis, of which I am already aware, and which is absolutely of no use to the OP. I was hoping others who were aware of it would restrain themselves from bringing it up here if I included such a caveat, but apparently I was quite wrong. I guess in future I will need to use the phrase "in standard analysis" even though this is likely to cause some confusion.

Comment: @Ian I will address your concern about my "tone" first; sorry if it came across as condescending -- I certainly didn't mean it. I was only surprised by your dismissive attitude towards the existence and use of infinitesimals as a kind of proper practice by implying that their use is somewhat informal. In your explicit statement, I still find your attitude disconcerting, since you make it seem as if the use of differentials is somewhat dirty or not worthy of being used or even discussed at all. But I shall stop here. I only meant to allow OP know that they are perfectly respectable objects.

Comment: I promised to stop talking, but talk of condescension when you utter with an air of finality that something is *absolutely* of no use to someone who mentions and asks about them. SMH!

Comment: @Allawonder I at least didn't say that. Maybe "usually" wasn't a great way to communicate the caveat that nonstandard analysis is a thing that you can actually formalize. "In standard analysis" would be a better phrase for this, though as I said it is likely to cause confusion for beginners. Still, I did say "when working formally", and described some intuitive usage of the concept beforehand as well.

Comment: @Allawonder: it turns out that I didn't want to enter the controversy about the meaning of differentials and their modern definition, as I usually do. I just wanted to give a negative answer that is easy to understand, despite not being rigorous. You can behead me if you want.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Must we lie that truth may prevail, or that we may avoid "controversy"? By the way, there is no controversy about what differentials mean. They have a rigorous definition and form a valid way (and in my opinion the only human-intuitive way) of looking at the infinitesimal calculus.

Comment: @Allawonder: I knew my head would fall.